# java.sql.ResultSet as user defined

Tags: java, connection-pooling, resultset

I have an old application which I need to optimize in which my method returns `java.sql.ResultSet` and also I have single connection so now I need to implement connection pooling now the problem is if I close the connection than resultset will give exception when doing `rs.next()` so I want such a class similar to ResultSet which we can say is detached from Connection also such that i don't have to make changes on my JSPs where i have used `ResultSet` object.

Comment: What you describe is a wild, vicious, unmaintainable hack to cover up for bad design. You really must change that JSP code **not** to use the raw `ResultSet` object. Think MVC.

Comment: You can think about [CachedRowSet](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javaserverpages/cachedrowset/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution I had used `CachedRowSet`

```
package taher.connection;
import com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;

/**
 *
 * @author taher_JAVAHUNTER
 */

public class DataTransaction {

private final static String username = "test";
private final static String password = "test";
private final static String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3309/test";
public Connection connection = null;
public Statement statement = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
public static int connectionCount = 0;

public DataTransaction(boolean setCon) {
    try {
        setConnection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in Connection:" + e.toString());
    }
}
public static BasicDataSource dataSource;

public void setConnection() throws SQLException {
    try {
        if (dataSource == null) {
            dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            try {
                dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
                dataSource.setUrl(url);
                dataSource.setUsername(username);
                dataSource.setPassword(password);
                dataSource.setMaxActive(100);
                dataSource.setMaxWait(10000);
                dataSource.setMaxIdle(10);
                if (connection == null || connection.isClosed()) {
                    System.out.println(" requeition CONNECTION WITH FIRST SERVER.");
                    connection = dataSource.getConnection();
                    connectionCount++;
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("***Connection Requisition*** Could not connect to the database msg :" + e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("NumActive : "+dataSource.getNumActive());
            System.out.println("NumIdle : "+dataSource.getNumIdle());
            System.out.println("NumTestsPerEvictionRun : "+dataSource.getNumTestsPerEvictionRun());
            if (connection == null || connection.isClosed()) {
                connection = dataSource.getConnection();
                connectionCount++;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("open connection exception" + e);
    }
}

public CachedRowSet viewQuery(String query) throws SQLException, Exception {
    //query = query;
    CachedRowSetImpl crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
    CachedRowSet crs2 = null;

    try {
        if (connection.isClosed()) {
            setConnection();
        }
    System.out.println("Connection count 1 : " + connectionCount);

        statement = connection.createStatement();
        rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

        crs.populate(rs);
        crs2 = crs.createCopy();
        closeConnection();
        System.out.println("Connection count 2 : " + connectionCount);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return crs2;
}

public void closeConnection() throws SQLException {
    try {
        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        } else {
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();                
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }


}

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, Exception {
    DataTransaction dt = new DataTransaction(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ResultSet rs = dt.viewQuery("select * from tbl_test");
        //ResultSet rs = dt.viewQuery("select * from tbl_test",0);
        System.out.println("Connection closed : " + dt.connection.isClosed());
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("testId : " + rs.getString(1));
            System.out.println("testName : " + rs.getString(2));
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would recommend:

Write your persistence methods so you pass the connection in.  Let another object (e.g. a service) manage getting the connection out of the pool, transactions, and cleanup.

Your persistence classes should create and close `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet` objects within the method scope.  Do *not* pass a `ResultSet` around; map it into an object or data structure of some kind and return that to the caller.

Your JSPs should *not* be dealing with `ResultSets`.  They should be iterating over the object or data structure that you mapped the `ResultSet` into when you called the persistence tier.

Let me guess: your JSPs are filled with scriptlets.  You must throw that away, too.  Time to learn JSTL.

Read about Model-2 MVC.

Comment: +1 Very organized answer. Only problem I see here is the endless duplication of resource management code. It is hard to fight, though, without AOP or Java 8 closures.

Comment: Not hard to fight.  Use Spring's SimpleJDBCTemplate and it's taken care of.  If that's too much, some static database utility methods to close resources and make generic SQL calls would do it without any trouble.  No need for aspects or closures.  Keeping everything in a well-defined persistence tier should be sufficient.

Comment: Heh heh, exactly. I classified such an answer as out of scope. If not, then definitely Springize the whole thing, introduce proper declarative transaction management, don't pass Connections around, etc. etc.

Comment: see my code is messy i cant make changes on jsp level so need such a solution which gives maximum output with minimum effort

Comment: Yes, you can make changes.  You choose not to.  Make the case and do it, or suffer from the built in limitations.  Good luck.